# Do flies avoid infrared light?

Tags: entomology, ethology, light, pest-control

If flies avoid IR light, many places can be kept free from flies using IR light. We see insect repellers in many restaurants, but they don't seem to work well. Can IR be a safe & effective alternative?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio@SE. What have you done to answer your question? you should edit your question to add this information, it will help you get more specific answers

Comment: What kind of "flies"?

Comment: I doubt very much that sunlight, what they like to bask in, is an issue for them. UV and Blue light you mean? is use in fly traps?!?! flies are made to spend all day in light, and IR by it's nature is the most beneficial light as it's in between a mug warmth and an LED. anything warm is likely to emit IR.